# How to correctly use the method merge() of Map <String, StringBuilder> to append a specific character?

Tags: java, collections

I have the following maps:

```
Map<String, StringBuilder> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, StringBuilder> map2 = new HashMap<>();

StringBuilder sb11 = new StringBuilder("0004001:00:00;0004002:00:00;0004002:01:01;");
StringBuilder sb12 = new StringBuilder("0005001:00:00;0005002:00:00;0005002:01:01;");
StringBuilder sb13 = new StringBuilder("0007001:00:00;0007002:00:00;0007002:01:01;");
  
map1.put("0004", sb11);
map1.put("0005", sb12);
map1.put("0007", sb13);
  
StringBuilder sb21 = new StringBuilder("0004002:00:00;0004002:00:00;0004002:01:01;");
StringBuilder sb22 = new StringBuilder("0007002:00:00;0007002:00:00;0007002:01:01;");
StringBuilder sb23 = new StringBuilder("0008002:00:00;0008002:00:00;0008002:01:01;");
  
map2.put("0004", sb21);
map2.put("0007", sb22);
map2.put("0008", sb23);
```

On the basis of these maps, I need to obtain a result map that for identical keys in both maps above has a concatenation of values separated by "|".

For different keys also the condition must be met - if the key is present only in map1 then only the value is added, and if the key is present only in map2 then "|" should be added before the value. In short, I mean this result:

map1

```
0004 - 0004001:00:00;0004002:00:00;0004002:01:01;
0005 - 0005001:00:00;0005002:00:00;0005002:01:01;
0007 - 0007001:00:00;0007002:00:00;0007002:01:01;
```

map2

```
0004 - 0004002:00:00;0004002:00:00;0004002:01:01;
0007 - 0007002:00:00;0007002:00:00;0007002:01:01;
0008 - 0008002:00:00;0008002:00:00;0008002:01:01;
```

expected result map

```
0004 - 0004001:00:00;0004002:00:00;0004002:01:01;|0004002:00:00;0004002:00:00;0004002:01:01;
0005 - 0005001:00:00;0005002:00:00;0005002:01:01;
0007 - 0007001:00:00;0007002:00:00;0007002:01:01;|0007002:00:00;0007002:00:00;0007002:01:01;
0008 - |0008002:00:00;0008002:00:00;0008002:01:01;
```

I almost managed to find a solution but I have a problem with the case when the key only exists in map2, I have no idea how to change my code so that the "|" sign is added in front of the value.

How can I fix it?

My code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Map<String, StringBuilder> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, StringBuilder> map2 = new HashMap<>();

    StringBuilder sb11 = new StringBuilder("0004001:00:00;0004002:00:00;0004002:01:01;");
    StringBuilder sb12 = new StringBuilder("0005001:00:00;0005002:00:00;0005002:01:01;");
    StringBuilder sb13 = new StringBuilder("0007001:00:00;0007002:00:00;0007002:01:01;");
      
    map1.put("0004", sb11);
    map1.put("0005", sb12);
    map1.put("0007", sb13);
      
    StringBuilder sb21 = new StringBuilder("0004002:00:00;0004002:00:00;0004002:01:01;");
    StringBuilder sb22 = new StringBuilder("0007002:00:00;0007002:00:00;0007002:01:01;");
    StringBuilder sb23 = new StringBuilder("0008002:00:00;0008002:00:00;0008002:01:01;");
      
    map2.put("0004", sb21);
    map2.put("0007", sb22);
    map2.put("0008", sb23);

      
      //Merge maps
      map2.forEach((key, value) -> map1.merge(key, value, (v1, v2) -> v1.append("|").append(v2)));
      
      map1.entrySet().forEach(entry->{
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());  
    });
}
```

Result:

```
0007 0007001:00:00;0007002:00:00;0007002:01:01;|0007002:00:00;0007002:00:00;0007002:01:01;
0004 0004001:00:00;0004002:00:00;0004002:01:01;|0004002:00:00;0004002:00:00;0004002:01:01;
0005 0005001:00:00;0005002:00:00;0005002:01:01;
0008 0008002:00:00;0008002:00:00;0008002:01:01;
```

Comment: You don't get a result Map with `merge`, because you modify the source Map. Why don't you just write your code using two loops, that iterate over map1 and map2 and put your desired result in a third map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge` simply cannot do the job. `merge` will *only* invoke that function if both `map1` and `map2` have the provided key; otherwise, if only one of the two maps has a mapping for that key, that mapping is just inserted, without modification - thus, no leading `|`. There is no way to make `merge` work differently, so you just cannot use it here. Get rid of it.

As usual, it's just simpler to read if you use lambdas only where they seem like a clear win, instead of as the universal hammer that is so good you want to use it for everything, including buttering your bread.

```
for (var entry : map2.entrySet()) {
     map1
       .computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), x -> new StringBuilder())
       .append("|")
       .append(entry.getValue());
}
```

Simple enough, and does precisely what you want.

If you really are hell bent on using that hammer to smear this slice of bread, the method you really want is `compute`. You'll have to mess around with `null` though, it's not going to be any prettier.

NB: `collection.forEach`, as well as `collection.stream.forEach` are bad code style - you lose local variable, control flow, and exception transparency, and you gain absolutely nothing whatsoever in trade. Why pick a strictly inferior option? If you find it acceptable to dump e.g. `someList.forEach(System.out::println);` on a single line, I'm having a hard time imagining what kind of non-crazy argument you might care to provide for disallowing `for (var v : someList) System.out.println(v);`, which is just as short, and deals with local vars, control flow, and checked exceptions much better. I've done you the service of removing that bit. As I said, use lambdas when they get you something tangible, such as the `computeIfAbsent` above. That'd be far more convoluted without them.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for explaining why merge() is not the right choice.

Comment: Ordinary loops are still a good tool and there’s no reason to replace all loops with other constructs, that’s right. And `var` is a great win for them. However, calling `forEach` “bad coding style” goes way too far. You don’t always need additional control flow statements or checked exceptions. A collection’s specialized `forEach` may result in higher performance than a stateful `Iterator` and in case of maps, `map.forEach((key,value) -> …)` is simpler than going through the `entrySet()` and having to call `getKey()` and `getValue()` manually. Don’t replace one dogmatic style with another.

Comment: `forEach` to run a lambda you already have (e.g. was passed in as method arg), or as a terminator on a stream where you did a bunch of stream ops is fine. But on its own, it looks like a classic for loop and does the exact same thing. Thus, it becomes a style debate (and you know how those go. tabs v spaces anybody?) - except in this case, one is far inferior. A/B rule: If you have 2 ways of doing it, and A covers all the bases B covers, and many more to boot - always use A. Better code style: More consistent, lower learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is what I came up with. It simply iterates over one map checking the keys and putting the appropriate values in the other map.  If each map contains the same key, then `put`, both in `map1` separated by `|`, otherwise, put the `map2 key` and `value` in `map1` with the `prefixed` with `|`.

```
for(String key : map2.keySet()) {
    if (map1.containsKey(key)) {
        map1.put(key, map1.get(key).append("|").append(map2.get(key)));
    } else {
        map1.put(key, map2.get(key).insert(0, "|"));
    }
}
    
map1.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
0007=0007001:00:00;0007002:00:00;0007002:01:01;|0007002:00:00;0007002:00:00;0007002:01:01;
0004=0004001:00:00;0004002:00:00;0004002:01:01;|0004002:00:00;0004002:00:00;0004002:01:01;
0005=0005001:00:00;0005002:00:00;0005002:01:01;
0008=|0008002:00:00;0008002:00:00;0008002:01:01;
```

If you want them sorted by key, then make `map1` a `TreeMap`